# How to understand the concept of create classes or methods joined together in Java

Tags: java

I want to know the concept of inner methods called one time example in Java.

```
Object ob = new Object().toString().charAt(0);
```

**My question:**

Are `toString()` and `charAt(0);` are classes or methods joined together using dot?

I confused how to ask these question if you understand my bad grammar please help me.

Comment: Each method of those returns a object, you are just chaining the call in the next object.

Comment: And every object has its own set of methods that can be called. Note that the return type void is not a object and don't have methods to be called on it (not at your example but it would break the chain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "fluent interfaces" or method chaining. We can achive this with returning of object itself. Fluent apis used everywhere basic example of it is Builder classes.

In Java, Optional class or stream api is an example of fluent apis.

Here is an example builder class with fluend methods:

```
class ObjectBuilder {
    private SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

    public ObjectBuilder withPropertyX(int x) {
        someObject.setPropertyX(x);
        return this;
    }

    public ObjectBuilder withPropertyY(String y) {
        someObject.setPropertyY(y);
        return this;
    }

    public SomeObject build() {
        return someObject;
    }

}

ObjectBuilder builder = new ObjectBuilder();

SomeObject someObject = builder.withPropertyX(5).withPropertyY("test").build();
```

Another example with stream api:

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList();

    students.add("alice");
    students.add("jack");
    students.add("john");

    students.stream()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . Useful information you gave me.

Answer (score 3):

Each method of those returns a object, you are just chaining the call in the next object.

The equivalent of

```
char c = new Object().toString().charAt(0);
```

is the following code:

```
Object obj = new Object();
String objectStr = obj.toString();
char c = objectStr.charAt(0);
```